# How can i make a cache for the API res? (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, react-hooks, state

I've been trying a lot to cache the response of the API but I couldn't figure out how to do it.
I'm trying to make a cache that saves the response for 20 minutes.

If someone could please sandbox me the answer I'll be grateful!

**App.js:** (This is where I fetch the API)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import GetApi from './components/GetApi';

function App() {
  const [ratesList, setRatesList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchApi() {
      try {
        const requestUrl = 'https://www.live-rates.com/rates';
        const response = await fetch(requestUrl);
        const responseJSON = await response.json();
        console.log(responseJSON);
        setRatesList(responseJSON);
      } catch {}
    }
    fetchApi();
  }, []);

  return <GetApi ratesList={ratesList} />;
}

export default App;
```

**GetApi.js:** (This is where i render the response)

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function GetApi({ ratesList }) {
  return (
    <ul className="post-list">
      {ratesList.map(post => (
        <li key={uuidv4()}>
          currency: {post.currency}
          <br />
          rate: {post.rate}
          <br />
          bid: {post.bid}
          <br />
          ask: {post.ask}
          <br />
          high: {post.high}
          <br />
          low: {post.low}
          <br />
          open: {post.open}
          <br />
          close: {post.close}
          <br />
          timestamp: {post.timestamp}
          <br />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

GetApi.propTypes = {
  ratesList: PropTypes.array,
};

GetApi.defaultProps = {
  ratesList: [],
};

export default GetApi;
```

Thank you !!!

Comment: You can use `useSWR` here a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/swr-0n32d?from-embed)

Comment: First of all thank you for you're comment!
but, i can only see that it's just fetching a API response data and not caching.